# Ajax not refreshing

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to setup a register box to create new account. I am trying to load the html form through ajax and passing data to a php file.

I want to make the div which is containing the form to reload every time when the "register" button is hit to get the result from the php script and display it out. However, my code seems not working properly (The ajax handling div will not load the form ). Below are my codes:

Register.php:

```
<?php

            session_start();
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
            $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
            $repwd = $_POST['repwd'];
            $lname = $_POST['lname'];
            $fname = $_POST['fname'];

            $isValidEmail = 1;
            if (substr_count($email, '@') != 1){
                    $isValidEmail = 0;
            }

            if($pwd != $repwd){ //check if password and re-entered passwords are the same

                $_SESSION['error']      = 1;
                $_SESSION['message']    = 'Password and Re-entered Password are different.';


            } else if( strlen($pwd) < 6 || strlen($pwd) > 64 ) { //check if password is 6 - 64 characters
                $_SESSION['error']    = 1;
                $_SESSION['message']  = 'Password must be 6 - 64 characters.';

            } else if( strlen($email) > 255) { //check if the email is too long

                $_SESSION['error']      = 1;
                $_SESSION['message']    = 'Email exceeded maximum length.';

            } else if ($isValidEmail != 1){

                $_SESSION['error']     = 1;
                $_SESSION['message']   = 'Invalid Email.';


            } else if (ctype_space($lname) || ctype_space($fname)){
               $_SESSION['error']     = 1;
               $_SESSION['message']   = 'Please enter your name.';

            } else {    
                if ($mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "my_db")){

                    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?");
                    $stmt->bind_param('s',$email);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->bind_result($result);
                    $stmt->fetch();
                    $stmt->close();

                    if ($result == $email) { //check if the input email exists in the database, duplicated user
                        $_SESSION['error']    = 1;
                        $_SESSION['message']  = 'Email '.$email.' is already used.';

                    } else {  

                        $hash = hash('sha256', $pwd);

                        function createSalt()
                        {
                            $string = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
                            return substr($string, 0, 3);
                        }

                        $salt = createSalt();
                        $hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);

                        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users ( email, lastName, firstName, password, salt )
                                VALUES ( ? , ?, ?, ? ,? )");
                        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $email, $lname, $fname, $hash, $salt);
                        if ($stmt->execute()){
                            $_SESSION['message']  = 'Registered.';

                        } else { 
                            $_SESSION['error']   = 1;
                            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Database query error occured.';

                        }
                        $stmt->close();

                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['error']   = 1;
                    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Error connecting to the database.';

                }
            }
            header("Location: Home.php");   
            $mysqli->close();
        ?>
```

ajax.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

                $('#submit_register').click(function(){
                    $('#register_form').submit( function(){
                        $.ajax({
                            type:       'POST',
                            url :       'Register.php',
                            data:       $('#register_form').serialize(),
                            success:    function () {
                                            var myURL = "Register_form.php#register_div";
                                            $('#ajaxHandle').load(myURL);
                                            return false; 
                                        },
                        });
                    });
                });
});
```

Register_form.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <?php session_start(); ?>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="span-23 prepand-top last" id="register_div" style="background:gray;">
            <div id="wrapper_register" class="span-21 last" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-left:20px; padding-bottom:20px;">
                <form id="register_form" action="register.php" method="post">

                        <legend class="large">Register</legend>
                                <?php

                                    if ($_SESSION['message']){
                                            $class = "";
                                            if ($_SESSION['error']){
                                               $class = "error";
                                            } else {
                                               $class = "success";
                                            }
                                            echo "<div class=\"$class span-4 last\">";
                                            echo $_SESSION['message'];
                                            echo "</div>";

                                            unset ($_SESSION['error']);
                                            unset ($_SESSION['message']); 
                                    }
                                ?>
                        <div class="span-23 prepand-top last">
                        <p>E-mail address: <br>
                        <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="255" /></p><br>
                        <p>Last Name: <br><input type="text" name="lname" maxlength="255" /></p><br>
                        <p>First Name: <br>
                        <input type="text" name="fname" maxlength="255" /></p><br>
                        <p>Password: <br>
                        <input type="password" name="pwd" /><p class="quiet">6 - 64 characters</p><br>
                        <p>Re-enter Password: <br><input type="password" name="repwd" /></p><br>
                        <input id="submit_register" type="submit" value="Register" /><br>
                        </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am doing something wrong? Any advice will be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried a tool like firebug, chrome web inspector or fiddler to inspect the ajax request?  Your success callback will only fire if you recieve a http status 200 from the server, you are likely receiving a 400 or 500 status due to a syntax or logical error in your PHP.

Comment: please read more about [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)

Comment: I dont see you importing the ajax.js in your register_form.php file (<script src="ajax.js">)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I have put the refreshing jquery code in the wrong place. It worked when I put it within the .submit scope:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {   
        $('#submit_register').click(function(){
            $('#register_form').submit( function(){
                $.post(
                    'Register.php', 
                    $(this).serialize()
                );
                var myURL = "Register_form.php#register_div";
                $('#ajaxHandle').load(myURL);
                return false;
            });
        });
    });
```